# MongooseError: Operation `blacklistScema.find()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

Tags: mongoose, discord.js

This error only suddenly showed up it has worked before.

mongoose version: 5.12.6

most of the other answers I've seen have been about awaiting the mongoose connection before looking up the data.
I am using the wokcommands npm package for database connection/command handling and know its not the connection to the database.

here is my code

```js
  try {
    await blackListSchema.find().then((data) => {
      if (data) {
        data.forEach((val) => {
          blacklistedWords.set(val.guild, val.words);
        });
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
```

What I've tried:

- removing await from find/findOne/findOneAndUpdate callbacks
- wrapped all find/findOne requests in a try/catch block
- removing node_modules and reinstalling mongoose

Comment: how are you trying to connect to mongoose?
show the `mongoose.connect()` code

Comment: await mongoose.connect(mongoPath, {
    keepAlive: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    ...dbOptions,
  })

Comment: Edit to update instead of commenting.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occurs when you have a slow internet connection or no connection at all. This happened twice in my case. So, just make sure that you have a decent internet connection.

Also make sure that your connection with the database works or not.

Thanks

Comment: I have pretty good internet so I don't think that is the problem